# Android SQLite Update stops working after calling it two times

Tags: android, sqlite

I have problems in updating rows in SQLite database in my Android application. It works successfully only, if I update it two times. But when I try to do it on the third time, it doesn't update the same row anymore.

LogCat doesn't show any exceptions. `db.update()` returns `'1'`.

I've searched similar issues on StackOverflow and the web. People advic]sed to remove `db.close();` from `database-helper`, because I call it several times, or to use `db.update` method instead of `db.rawQuery()` or `db.execSQL()`.

I also tested my query in SQLite client, and it works as it's supposed to.

Here is code of simple database-helper method:

```
public int updateEventDoneMark(Event event)
{
    ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
    args.put("completed", event.getCompleted());  
    return db.update("Event", args, "id" + "='" +event.getId() + "'", null);
}
```

Is there some SQLite-related issue I should know while I update one database entry several times in a row?

Comment: You may wish to switch to positional parameters: `db.update("Event", args, "id=?", params);` where `String[] params={event.getId()};` Beyond that, there's no magical "SQLite stops working after two updates" limit. Do make sure that your threading is working properly, that the code is actually getting executed, etc.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for quick response! I've tried your suggestion and it doesn't make difference.
There is no any other thread which changes the data neither. Code executes every time and every time returns '1' as number of affected.rows.

Comment: What does your content provider update and URI match look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does your content provider update and URI match look like?

Typical Content providers have a  URI for each Table/View for a single row where _id is passed as a where_argument and a URI for multiple rows which uses where and where_arguments to select the rows to be updated.

Also it looks like you update by id.  Android really want the id column named "_id", although I don't think is currently your issue, but it really depends on the URI it's using.  Content Providers are usually coded with the _id and select by the column for a single row based on _id. That's why I want to see content provider.  Your also selecting by the id yourself, this doesn't seem normal, although it could be accomplished, but not the norm.  Typically the where part is something like 'colunm name = ?" and the next parameter where_arguments is a string array containing the value to replace the '?'.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have not used Content Provider and tried to execute queries directly, this is generally a bad idea. Once I start using Content Provider the problem had solved by itself.

Comment: sorry for waiting for two years to accept the answer